# Best regularity of free boundary problem modeled by laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\partial\Omega $ be a compact hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{n} $, $ f: \partial \Omega \to \mathbb {R} $ a non-negative function. It is possible to find another compact hypersurface $\Gamma = \partial \Omega '\subset \Omega $, such that the problem below is soluble

\begin{cases}
    \text{$\Delta u = 0$   in   $\Omega\setminus \Omega'$} \\
    \text{$u=f$  in  $\partial \Omega$} \\
    \text{$u=0$  , $u_{\eta}=1$ in  $\Gamma$  ,} \\
\end{cases}

where $\eta$ is the inner normal vector to $\Gamma$?

If we extend $u$ by zero inside $\Omega'$, thus $u\geq 0$ in $\Omega$. The free boundary of the problem, the surface $\Gamma$ becomes $\partial\{u>0\}$.

**Aff**: *Notice that, because of Hopf's
maximum principle, the best regularity one should hope for u in
­, is Lipschitz continuity.*

My question is how to use th Hopf lemma for the show that statement????